# Most frequent array of an array of arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I made this method that takes an array of arrays and should return the array most frequent in my array of arrays, but it does print only a[0], which means that one of my expressions doesn't get evaluated. I don't understand which and why.

```
private static int[] frequency(int[][] a) {
    for (int z = 0; z < a.length; z++) {
        for (int t = 0; t < a[1].length; t++) {
            System.out.print(a[z][t]+" ");

        }System.out.println();}
    int count = 1, tempCount;
    int[] popular = a[0];
    int[] temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        temp = a[i];
        tempCount = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            if ((temp == a[j])&&(i!=j)) {
                tempCount++;
            }

        }
        if (tempCount > count) {
            popular = temp;
            count = tempCount;

        }
    }

    return popular;
}
```

Comment: did you try a[z].length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot compare two different arrays for element-by-element equality with this expression:

```
temp == a[j]
```

This checks *reference equality* only, meaning that it evaluates `true` only when `temp` is literally the same array object.

In order to fix this, replace with a call of `Arrays.equals(temp, a[j])`

Comment: So I should loop through each elements, instead?

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc Essentially, yes. The need to do that is so pervasive among Java programmers, though, that Java designers have added an API to dot that (see the update to the answer).